# input placeholder line-height issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, placeholder

[image]

**What is the issue?**

There is a input box with height 36px as show in above image.
In IE10 placeholder is not vertically middle.

Comment: Can you please post the css that applies to the inputs? It's tricky to see what might be causing it without the code.

Comment: If you use line-height: Try adding `vertical-align: middle` to the text

Comment: You don't need `line-height`, share your complete code http://jsfiddle.net/VNrsQ/

Comment: Do you load some kind of reset css? If not maybe you should.

Comment: vertical-align: middle did not work here, I had used bootstrap 2.3.2 css. What I have understood from this is, if we give height to input we need to set line-height for having it vertically centered in IE10.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For all inputs just give

```
line-height:normal;
```

it will take normal line-height and will work fine in all browsers.

Comment: So why is normal not the standard , great answer tho! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I usually do `line-height: inherit;`, but this is a better strategy!

Answer (score 1):

I usually set a height and line-height to the **input[type=text]** and inherit these properties to **::placeholder**.

```
height: inherit;
line-height: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use waterwark js to fix this issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/maxim75/yJuF3/

Check out fiddle.

```
<input type="text" id="Text1" />
```

Comment: I had issue with vertical alignment of placeholder, I think you have shared above demo for having placeholder.

Comment: Yes, just adding placeholder property in your input tag won't guarantee the alignment of it perfectly on every browser. So you can go for watermark JS solution, if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this late--I found a solution that worked in Twitter Bootstrap (3.1) as well as a few other tests I ran.

Simply add to the input element:

```
height: inherit;
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Applied same 36px line-height to input[type="text"].

**Side effect:**

Before giving line-height: 36px it was working fine in all browser. As I applied 
36px line-height to input[type="text"], below is what happened  in Safari:

[image]

**Second Solution:**

Apply line-height with IE hack.
That is as follows

```
input[type="text"] {
    line-height: 36px\9; // CSS Hack only for IE.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding line-height for placeholder on Firefox specifically fixes the issues. Otherwise adding `line-height` to `::placeholder` breaks Safari.

```css
  &::-moz-placeholder {
    line-height: 36px; // this should be equal to height of the input
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer of `line-height:normal;` worked for me in almost every circumstance. But Firefox when the input height is specified in px was still giving me issues. I ended up needing to target the browser for this. I used the WordPress global $is_gecko, but there are many other solutions for other platforms out there for targeting the browser with a class, which I find to be the more durable solution than using any `-moz` hacks. It sucks targeting specific browsers, but sometimes it's needed.

Not sure why, but `line-height: revert;` seems to work in Firefox. Seems like if the main `input` has `line-height: normal`, then setting the placeholder explicitly to `line-height: normal` as well should have the exact same effect as `line-height: revert` but it does not seem to work that way in ff.

```css
input.special-field {
    height: 48px;
    line-height: normal;
}
input.special-field::placeholder {
    height: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    vertical-align: revert;
}
.gecko input.special-field::placeholder {
    line-height: revert;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
vertical-align:middle;
```